# API to strip out second-level domains (or the complete list in CSV or whatever format)

Tags: javascript, networking, dns, network-programming, web-development-server

Where could I find a code (javascript would be the best) to strip out the *www* and *second-level domain names* from URLs?

**Example:**

> ```
> www.ynet.co.il -> ynet (stripped 'co.il' - two tokens)
> www.nike.com -> nike (stripped 'com' - one token)
> ```

etc

As a second best - the full list of second-level domains (preferably in CSV or any other format) will be welcomed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Java, [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) can help you here.

You can use [`InternetDomainName.topPrivateDomain()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html#topPrivateDomain%28%29) together with [`publicSuffix()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html#publicSuffix%28%29) to solve your problem.

Guava (as well as Mozilla/Firefox, Chrome and Opera) use the [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/) for this functionality (the [raw data is here](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1)).

[tld.js](https://github.com/oncletom/tld.js) is a JavaScript library that uses that data as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/2428561 something like this? Search for 'javascript url parser' in google

Comment: That one is obvious, the tricky part of the question is to know what to strip out.

Comment: I'll be happy to hear any justified reason for the downvoice.

Comment: you can use 'parser.hostname' and filter any value out of the following list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains (I did not downvote btw)